# Laravel Passport Personal access client not found. Please create one. in tests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am having a little confusion with Laravel Passport. I am using Laravel purely as an API, and i have a completely seperate React app for the frontend which i want to authenticate using tokens. Also there are apps in the works. I was finding that I would have to run `php artisan passport:install` on every boot (docker), so i created a seeder which would seed the data that i need, that took care of one problem;

```php
class OauthSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run(): void
    {
        DB::table('oauth_clients')->insert([
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'App Personal Access Client',
            'secret' => '1bYFWnATx9ZnbVWkXdBnSf3r77bMYyqW6viF4VMs',
            'redirect' => 'http://localhost',
            'personal_access_client' => 1,
            'password_client' => 0,
            'revoked' => 0,
            'created_at' => now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ]);

        DB::table('oauth_clients')->insert([
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'App Password Grant Client',
            'secret' => '2pwFGyvEWu53pKBNCG1QjtyVwK9NtvHyOrOUPGlE',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'redirect' => 'http://localhost',
            'personal_access_client' => 0,
            'password_client' => 1,
            'revoked' => 0,
            'created_at' => now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ]);

        DB::table('oauth_personal_access_clients')->insert([
            'id' => 1,
            'client_id' => 1,
            'created_at' => now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now when i boot up my environment i am able to use Postman to go to my routes and it all works perfect.

My login controller is very simple, it just gets the email / password and returns a token

```php
public function execute($request)
{
    $payload = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];

    if (! auth()->attempt($payload)) {
        throw new InvalidCredentialsException();
    }

    return auth()->user()->createToken('myapp')->accessToken;
}
```

The problem comes in when I try and test. I have the following test;

```php
namespace Tests\Feature\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class LoginControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function it_returns_a_token_when_trying_to_log_in(): void
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create();

        $this->postJson('api/login', [
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => 'password',
        ])
            ->assertOk();
    }
}
```

It is failing with the following;

```
Personal access client not found. Please create one.
```

Comment: If you're using Docker, why are you not persisting the database with volume storage? You're going to loose more than just your Passport data if you ever restart your containers.... Also, where are you running your tests? Locally, it won't have access to the DB... You need to run your tests from within the container than is networked to the database....

Comment: Yes its all setup properly, the DB is being persisted and the tests are running from within the container

Comment: If it was set up properly, you wouldn't be seeding your database on every container run. Are you running your tests prior to your database having these seeded values or after? What do you see if you try read from that table in your tests? IE `DB::table(....)` is the key there?

Comment: I'm not seeding it on every boot ... I am in development stage, so from time to time i am seeding new data

Comment: It also looks like the [RefreshDatabase](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) trait is causing most your issues with your given scenario. It appears that is spins up an alternative database, but you can verify - as said above - with attempting to see if that key exists at runtime of your test